# AWS Lambda: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 106534017 bytes" after adding single file

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, serverless-framework

When trying to deploy my lambdas using AWS through the serverless framework I had no problems until I tried adding the ffmpeg binary.

Now the ffmpeg binaries I have tried to add have ranged from 26 mb to 50 mb. Whichever I add, I get the following error:

```
UPDATE_FAILED: WhatsappDocumentHandlerLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 106534017 bytes (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ...)" (RequestToken: ..., HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

The problem is that I did not add the file to this function. I added it to a completely different one.

I have tried the following things:

- Creating an "empty" function that only contains the ffmpeg binary and a function handler
- Creating a layer that only contains the ffmpeg binary
- Deleting the ffmpeg binary (the error goes away and deployment succeeds
- Varying sizes of ffmpeg binaries between 26 and 50mb
- Getting the ffmpeg-lambda-layer (https://github.com/serverlesspub/ffmpeg-aws-lambda-layer; https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/145266761615/ffmpeg-lambda-layer) and deploying it myself

When trying every single one of these options I get the UPDATE_FAILED error in a different function that surely is not too big.

I know I can deploy using a docker image but why complicate things with docker images when it should work?

I am very thankful for any ideas.

Comment: It sounds like something may be wonky with your config if its being assigned to a diff function. Perhaps you could delete locally and deploy the amazon layer using the deploy button then link to that? Not as integrated but might get you going.

Comment: @cyberwombat thank you for the response. I deployed the layer like you said and it is working fine. I decided to try adding a layer through my serverless deployment again and for some reason it works now without any errors. Could have been a hiccup on the AWS or serverless side? Anyways, I tried something yesterday and it threw an error, tried same thing today, it didn't. Love it.

Comment: Are you using individual function packaging? By default, all functions will use a single zip package, which is why other function might be failing for you here.

Comment: @pgrzesik No. The problem resolved itself when I redeployed the same code a day later. Seems to have been an AWS issue.

Comment: Today is another day where I try redeploying the exact same stack as yesterday but I get this error.